# Type gql-tag in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, graphql, graphql-js

I am working with GraphQL and I want to have strict typing in `gql`. Is it possible to make `result` variable to be shape of `ResultData` i.e. with the latest version of TypeScript. It is only about typing, not about runtime.

```
interface Data {
    one: string;
    two: number;
    three: {
        four: string;
        five: {
            six: Date;
        };
    };
}

// true means that this field must be added to query
type RecursivePartial<T> = {[P in keyof T]?: RecursivePartial<T[P]> | true};

function gql<T>(fields: RecursivePartial<T>) {
  // Some code about generating GraphQL query
}

const result = gql<Data>({one: true, three: {five: {six: true}}});

// type ResultData {
//     one: string;
//     three: {
//         five: {
//             six: Date;
//         };
//     };
// }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working for me in the playground:

```
interface Data {
    one: string;
    two: number;
    three: {
        four: string;
        five: {
            six: Date;
        };
    };
}

// Prevent widening of true to boolean in queries
type RecursivePartial1 = { [k: string]: RecursivePartial1 | true };
// true means that this field must be added to query
type RecursivePartial<T> = RecursivePartial1 & { [P in keyof T]?: RecursivePartial<T[P]> | boolean };

type RecursivePick<T, Q extends RecursivePartial<T>> =
  { [P in keyof T & keyof Q]:
    Q[P] extends RecursivePartial<T[P]> ? RecursivePick<T[P], Q[P]> : T[P] };

function gql<T, Q extends RecursivePartial<T>>(data: T, fields: Q): RecursivePick<T, Q> {
  // Some code about generating GraphQL query
}

declare const data: Data;
const result = gql(data, { one: true, three: { five: { six: true } } });

// type ResultData {
//     one: string;
//     three: {
//         five: {
//             six: Date;
//         };
//     };
// }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I copied this code to TypeScript playground and TS allowed me to have access to properties that I didn't select in `gql`

const result = gql(data, { one: true, three: { five: { six: true } } });
const another = result.three.four; // no errors, but I didn't select the `four` property above

Comment: Oops, in attempting to simplify the definition of `RecursivePick`, I broke it.  Please try again.